# SSL warning publishing role to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-role-environment

When publishing a role to Azure, the process stays in pending state and I eventually have to cancel the process.  The following warning gets repeated continuously "Warning: The server encountered an unknown failure: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

Up until now, I've had no problems publishing and not sure what's changed. Using VS2010, .NET 4.0, Windows Azure SDK Nov 2011.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033020/windows-azure-storage-certificate-expired

Answer (score 4):

Azure is experiencing a global outage due to expired SSL cert, so if this is happening on Feb 22 2013 then you are probably just hitting this global outage problem and there isn't anything you can do until Microsoft resolves their cert issues.